# Find the radius of convergence of this power serie

Tags: complex-analysis

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^n}{n!} \cdot (z-1)^n$. Here is how i start. Since i know that $$lim|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ so i did $$\frac{\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}(z-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}{\frac {n^n (z-1)^n}{n!}}$$. $$\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}(z-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \cdot \frac{n!}{n^n (z-1)^n}$$ after simplification i obtain $$\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n} \cdot |z-1|$$. $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n} \cdot |z-1|$$ $$\lim_{x\to\infty} (\frac{n+1}{n})^{n} \cdot |z-1|$$ $$\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+ 1/n)^n \cdot |z-1|$$ limit is $$e \cdot |z-1|$$ does that mean the radius of convergence is $e$ or do this computation even correct

Comment: correctomundo amigo

Comment: alright that means i was right all along i had some doubts about this that is why i post it. Gracias amigo

Comment: Of course, what this proves is that the series converges for every $z$ in the disk centered at $1$ of radius $1/e$. From this, one could show that the radius of convergence of the series $\sum\limits_n\frac{n^n}{n!}u^n$ is $1/e$. But the notion of radius of convergence for the series $\sum\limits_n\frac{n^n}{n!}(z-1)^n$ is unclear since there is no disk $D$ centered at $0$ such that the series converges for every $z$ in $D$.

Comment: @Did - the definition of radius of convergence does not require that the disk is centered at 0.

Comment: Yes i think it did say that

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is correct, but the final result means the radius of convergence is $\frac 1 e$, not $e$